# Не работает js как надо в html.

Tags: google-chrome, html, css, javascript

Делаю страничку регистрации на `html`. Прописываю `js` код. Если `<input name="extra" type="checkbox" id="extra">Yes</input>`нажат, то показать скрытый

```
<div id="extrax">
            <label for="extras">How did you know us?</label></br>
            <p><input name="extra" type="checkbox" >1</input>
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >2</input>
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >3</input>
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >4</input></p>
            <p><input name="extra" type="checkbox" >5</input>
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >6</input>
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >7</input>
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >8</input></p>
            <p><input name="extra" type="checkbox" >9</input> 
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >10</input> 
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >11</input> 
               <input name="extra" type="checkbox" >12</input></p>
        </div>
```

Вот соответственно код js:

```
function prepareHandlers(){
    document.getElementById("extra").onclick = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("extra").checked) {
            document.getElementById("extrax").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("extrax").style.display = "none";
        }
    };
}

window.onload = function() {
    prepareHandlers();
};
```

Надеюсь вы поможете разобраться почему, при нажатии на чекбокс ничего не происходит(
P.S.: Пробовал вставлять тег `script` в `head` и в конец `body`, все равно не пашет(

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по name: getElementsByName, а вы пытаетесь искать по ID, которого нет.

Comment: <input name="extra" type="checkbox" id="extra">Yes</input>

Comment: Он есть, просто не выделил его)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `onchange` вместо `onclick`

Comment: Не меняет ничего